# how do you convert a relative path to an absolute path under C++/ gtkmm?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

how do you convert a relative path to an absolute path under C++ and gtk?

Answer (score 1):

```
// For C++ with Gnome Gtkmm3 libraries
#include <string>
#include <glibmm.h>
#include <giomm.h>

using namespace std;

string PathRel2Abs(string relpath) {
  Glib::RefPtr<Gio::File> file = Gio::File::create_for_path(relpath);
  return file->get_path();
}
```